# Opening edb-database with page size more than 8192 on Vista

Tags: edb

I use

    `JetGetDatabaseFileInfo(db_name, &db_page_size, sizeof(db_page_size),JET_DbInfoPageSize);

    JetSetSystemParameter(NULL, NULL, JET_paramDatabasePageSize, db_page_size, NULL);`

to set the same page size of as a database have.
There is a database with page size == 32768. On windows 7 this code works perfectly. On Windows Vista JetSetSystemParameter returns JET_errInvalidParameter. Is there any way to open a database with page size of over 8192 on Windows Vista?

Answer (score 2):

No. 32k pages were added in Windows 7.

Even if the database had 8k pages, there are other Windows 7 changes that would make the Vista esent.dll unable to open the Win7-based database file.

If it's just for your own use, you can copy the Win7 esent.dll to a Vista machine. But I don't believe that it's permissible to redistribute esent.dll with your program.

-martin